# Bone's Location transformation coordinates disabled

Tags: animation, rigify

I was working with Rigify Rig for a character and created some of the bones, however, while working in pose mode, it appears that the location coordinates of all of the newly created bones are disabled but rotation coordinates are enabled. I would like to enable the location coordinates.
For reference, a screenshot is attached.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loc is disabled because theese bones are connected child of the previous bone on the chain, so their location is determined by that parent bone.

If you want to control the location also (and so disconnect the bone from the chain), you have to go to edit mode, select the bone and press Alt P > Disconnect Bone.

The bone will remain child, but unconnected (keep offset only), and you'll be free to move its location in pose mode.

Be aware that if the chain has some mechanism, like IK, it could get broken.